# Vertically align text with css

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to vertically center the text in my blue box?

markup:

```
<div class="btn-blue">
  <span class="icon"></span>
  Some awesome text here
</div>
```

and the styles:

```
.btn-blue {
  background-color: #446598;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px 0 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

.btn-blue .icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #00356b;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Here is the **fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/fSa6r/

Thanks.

Comment: this has been asked so many times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `line-height: 50px;` to the .btn-blue class and

`vertical-align: middle;` to the icon class

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/v7gr7/)**

When only one line of text is needed, I find that setting line-height to the height of the box is the easiest way to vertically center text.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to vertically align text, which you can check out here: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

My personal favourite is using CSS tables (not html tables):

html:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">Content here</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#parent {display: table;}

#child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another method to show a link as a button with icon. You could to improve this code using an sprite instead two separated images:

```
a.mybutton { 
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 30px; 
    color: #c00; 
}

a.mybutton:link, 
a.mybutton:visited, 
a.mybutton:active { 
    background: #fff url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59816767/assets/map-pin_off.png") left center no-repeat; 
}
a.mybutton:hover { background: #fff url("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59816767/assets/map-pin_on.png") left center no-repeat; }
```

Here is the: **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orisala/gUVYs/)**